# I'm using spatie/laravel-sitemap is it possible to set another APP_URL for these url

Tags: php, laravel, backend, sitemap, laravel-sitemap

here I'm using sitemap

```
    $sitemap = Sitemap::create()->add(Url::create('/content'));
    
    $sitemap->writeToFile(public_path($this->path));
```

and this is sitemap.xml

```
<url>
    <loc>http://api-core.test/content</loc>
    <lastmod>2020-09-09T11:30:51+04:30</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
```

is there any way to change api-core.test without changing env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to change baseurl
if string in `Url::create('http://example.com/content')` contain http
create function does not paste the url at the beginning of the string

sitemap will change to

```
<url>
     <loc>http://example.com/content</loc>
     <lastmod>2020-09-09T11:30:51+04:30</lastmod>
     <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
     <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
```

even if APP_URL is somthing else